# Automatic deployment with travis but build directory not found

Tags: firebase, travis-ci

I am currently trying to setup automatic deployment on my repository to make it deploy to firebase whenever it is updated.

However, I am getting "0 files found in build" and a "404 not found" error. I am guessing this is due to the /build in .gitignore.

How do I make it build and deploy in travis whenever a pull request is merged to the master branch? Below is the two files which might be relevant. Thanks!

firebase.json

```html
{
  "database": {
    "rules": "database.rules.json"
  },
  "hosting": {
    "public": "build",
    "ignore": [
      "firebase.json",
      "**/.*",
      "**/node_modules/**"
    ]
  }
}
```

.travis.yml

```html
language: node_js
node_js:
- node
deploy:
  provider: firebase
  token:
    secure: "asfa=42sdas42FA"
  skip_cleanup: true
  project: "afsd-dsd8"
```